# How do I compare two different streams of two different collections of firebase and return a document which is present in both in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, stream

`getMatches(String userId) async {

```
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection("users")
  .document(userId).collection("chosenList").snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection("users")
  .document(userId).collection("selectedList").snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot1) {
        if(!snapshot.hasData || !snapshot1.hasData) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();

        }
        for (DocumentSnapshot doc in snapshot.data) {
          for(DocumentSnapshot docs in snapshot1.data) {
            if(doc.documentID == docs.documentID) {
              print(docs.documentID);
            }
          }
        }

      });

  }
  
  );
```

}`I have a two different collections which has a list of documents with userId's. I need to compare both of them using stream and return the document which is present in both. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [rx package](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) to have more capabilities to Dart Streams, then you can use `CombineLatestStream.combine2<R, T, S>(Stream<R> r, Stream<T> t, S combiner(A a, B b)` like this

```
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

Stream<DocumentSnapshot> get combined => CombineLatestStream.combine2<FirebaseUser, FirebaseUser, DocumentSnapshot>(
     MyFirebaseStream.document(userId).snapshots(), //or whatever your first stream is
     MyOtherFirebaseStream.document(otherUserId).snapshots(), 
     (documentFirstStream, documentSecondStream) => {
        // Do the logic to extract and return the document that satisfy your condition here 
     }
   );
```

There are other methods to try depending of what you want exactly, `ZipStream.zip2` if you want to compare by pair (first element of each stream, second element of each stream, etc).

Maybe a bit of code to know what exactly you try to return from each stream could help to guide you more

Comment: EdwynZN, I want to merge 2 streams. I used your suggested `ZipStream.zip2(streamData1, streamData2, (a, b) => null);` but what should I write instead of `null`? Kindly suggest. Thanks.