# How do you compare values from two steams in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have two streams with values that I need to compare when one of the streams receives a new event. Right now I have a function that does almost what I want, except it is a Future instead of a stream, so it only fires once.

```dart
  Future<int> getUnreadMessages(String brfID, String conversationID, String uid) async {
    DocumentSnapshot conversation = await getConversation(brfID, conversationID).last;
    QuerySnapshot messages = await getMessages(brfID, conversationID, 10).last;
    int unread = 0;

    for (var message in messages.documents) {
      if (message.data['time'].millisecondsSinceEpoch > conversation.data['users'][uid]['lastRead'].millisecondsSinceEpoch) {
        unread++;
      }
    }
    return unread;
  }
```

How would I go about converting this to a stream instead? It would be easy if one of the values wasn't a stream; then I could just use Firestores `.where()`, but that dosn't work with two streams.

The two streams looks like this:

```dart
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getMessages(String brfID, String conversationID, [int limit]) {
    return brfCollection
        .document('$brfID/messaging/$conversationID')
        .collection('messages')
        .orderBy('time', descending: true)
        .limit(limit)
        .snapshots();
  }

Stream<DocumentSnapshot> getConversation(String brfID, String conversationID) {
    return brfCollection.document('$brfID/messaging/$conversationID').snapshots();
  }
```

Comment: Perhaps this answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62747647/how-do-i-compare-two-different-streams-of-two-different-collections-of-firebase/62747810#62747810

Comment: Yes, thank you. Don't know how I messed that before